# returning a array object from class object

Tags: java, object, return

```
public class abc<E>{

Arraylist<E> returnthis = new Arraylist();
public abc<E> fuction(E c)
{
  returnthis.add(c);
  return returnthis 
}

}
```

// main

```
abc array = new array();
   temp = array.add(4);
```

How can i return an arraylist  from a function which return object of a class.

Comment: what's the purpose of doing this. can't you just change the return type to List<E>?

Comment: Are you asking how to return something which isn't the method's return type?

Comment: not it can't be change that why i am asking

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, then you will need to add an accessor (or getter) method to your `abc` class -

```
List<E> returnthis = new ArrayList<>(); // <-- note caps and diamond operator.
public List<E> getList() {
  return returnthis;
}
```

Then you can

```
abc<Foo> array = new abc<>(); // <-- abc is generic
List<Foo> foos = array.getList(); // <-- like so
```

Finally, `abc` is a very poor class name. It's nondescript and doesn't follow Java capitalization conventions.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is hard to read.  It might be why you're having trouble understanding it.

You've got to make the return type match the variable you're returning.

```
public class Demo<E> {

    List<E> data = new ArrayList<E>();

    public List<E> addToData(E c) {
        data.add(c);
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(data);
    }

    public String toString() { return this.data.toString(); }
}
```

Comment: if i am returning class object from a function how can i print or read it's value

Comment: You can just print it if the class overrides java.lang.Object.toString().  If one of yours does not, make it so.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't seem to have the basics down of arrays quite yet as bits of that isn't right. First you need to understand returning an array object correctly. Here is an example:

```
ArrayList<E> myArray = new ArrayList<E>();
public ArrayList<E> getMyArray(){
    return myArray;
}
```

Secondly capitalize the class name my OCD is going crazy right now.

Now look at your array, it doesn't hold values of the class you just created if thats what your trying to do. I am not entirely sure what it is your trying to do yet though you need to fix up your code first.